# comparing user input to an array works with one function, but not another

Tags: c++, linux, chatbot

Here I am again. I am working on a cli based chatbot, and I am trying to make it answer to questions like "who made u?". I already got this working with the question "how are u?", and the function for who made it is just a copied and pasted version of how are u. ofc with a different array, a different array name and a different function name. it compiles without issues, I call the function in main() and I refer to the user input string. asking for the time works, asking for how it is works as well. thats my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void howareyouq(string const& user_input);
void whattimeisit(string const& user_input);
void whomadeu(string const& user_input);

int main()
{
    string user_input; //creating userinput variable
    cin >> user_input; //writing user input to user_input 

   howareyouq(user_input);
   whattimeisit(user_input);
   whomadeu(user_input);
}          

void howareyouq(string const& user_input)
{
    string howruq[] = {"how are you?", "hru?", "how r u?", "hru"}; //array for the valid thingies
    for (int i=0; i!=4; i++)
    { 
        if (user_input == howruq[i]) {  //if the array contains something equal to user_input, this gets executed
            cout << "Thanks, Im fine!" << endl; //the answer
        }
    }
}

void whattimeisit(string const& user_input)
{
    string thetimepls[] = {"timepls", "what time is it?", "how late is it?", "whats the time?", "time?"};
    for (int i=0; i!=5; i++) { 
        if (user_input == thetimepls[i]) {
            time_t now = time(0);
            char *date = ctime(& now);
            cout << "The local date and time : " << date << endl;
        }
    }
}

void whomadeu(string const& user_input)
{
    string whomadeyoua[] = {"who made you", "who made you?", "who programmed u?", "who programmed you", "which person made u?", "which person made u"}; //array for the valid thingies
    for (int i=0; i!=6; i++)
    { 
        if (user_input == whomadeyoua[i]){  //if the array contains something equal to user_input, this gets executed
            string whomadeuq[4] = {"who made u?", "Who made you?", "who made you", "Who made you"}; //array for the valid thingies
            if (user_input == whomadeuq[4]) {  //if the array contains something equal to user_input, this gets executed
                cout << "Big Smarty."; //the answer
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: `cin >> user_input;` won't read whitespace characters. Are you sure you got this working with the question "how are u?"

Comment: `if (user_input == whomadeuq[4])` ouch, out-of-range access!

Comment: sorry , my {} were set at the wrong space here before, I fixed it. (not the issue, only the {}'s)

Comment: how can I fix out of range access?

Comment: It seems you should add another loop and use the loop counter of this new loop instead of 4.

Comment: and how do I do that?